# Create Custom Cultures and then modify them using "Region and Language" dialog in Windows

Tags: c#, globalization, cultureinfo

I've just created and registered a new culture following the steps described in MSDN article: [How to: Create Custom Cultures](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms172469.aspx).

```
var cib = new CultureAndRegionInfoBuilder(CultureName, CultureAndRegionModifiers.None);
cib.LoadDataFromCultureInfo(new CultureInfo("cs-CZ"));
cib.LoadDataFromRegionInfo(new RegionInfo("CZ"));
cib.CultureNativeName = CultureNativeName;
cib.CultureEnglishName = CultureNativeName;
cib.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator = separator
cib.Register();
```

Everything looks just fine. I can see my new culture in "Region and Language" dialog in Windows. I can even load the culture back to my application.

When I change something directly in "Region and Language" dialog in Control Panel (let say NumberDecimalSeparator should be dot "." instead of comma ",") and then try to retrieve the culture:

```
var ci = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo(CultureName);
ci.ClearCachedData();
ci = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo(CultureName);
```

I've got still the same culture info I registered. Manual change is not projected in retrieved CultureInfo object.

Is that a proper behaviour or Am I doing something wrong?

**EDIT:**

If I think about it again, it is obviously the problem that I am running application in IIS under different user account than the user who is changing the culture info in Control Panel, because it is a **UserCustomCulture** as I've noticed.

**Correct question is, how can I register a culture to be common for all users (or at least for IIS user and some Admin user)?**

The reasons why I want to do this:

1. I want to be able to customize formatting used in the application.
2. I don't want to create GUI equivalent to the one in Control Panel inside my Web Application.
3. An administrator can simply set up formatting for the application in Control Panel.

Comment: At least try a logout + login to see if that clears any cached data.

Comment: The problem seems to be related to the fact that an application is running in IIS. I've tried to run simple asp.net application with the code above. If I run it in VS Development server, everything works fine. When I switch to IIS I am getting default values.

So probably problem is that app in IIS is running under different user account?